# Find the number of solutions of x+y+z=17?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the number of solutions of $x+y+z=17$ where $2\le x\le 5, 3\le y \le 6, 4\le z\le7$.

My approach:
The number of solutions with the indicated constraints is the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the expansion of 
($x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)$

I have changed the above polynomial to 
$x^9(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$

Now $x^{17}=x^9*x^8$

So I must now find the coefficient of $x^8$ in the expansion of ($1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$

$x_1+x_2+x_3=8$

This is equal to $C(3+8-1,8)=45$

However it takes into values of $x,y,z$ greater than $3$.

So I must subtract those combinations where either of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ is greater than $3$.

Let's suppose $x_1\ge 4$.Then

$x_1+x_2+x_3=4$
Solutions=$15$.

Similarly for $x_2,x_3$ we get $15$ solutions each. 
Total=$45$.
Now we must consider the case when more than one of $x_1+x_2+x_3\ge 4$.
For this we have $3$ solutions.

Total solutions=$48$.

Now I must subtract these from original solutions of $45$. This gives answer $=-3$.
But the correct answer is $3$.

What is wrong in this approach?

Comment: If the question regards an example or test question, and not the general approach, note that you get the result immediately since only $3 + 3 + 2 = 3 + 2 + 3 = 2 + 3 + 3 = 8$ for integers $\le 3$.

Comment: Three solutions not negative three :)
$$(x = 5,\;y = 6,\;z = 6),\;(x = 5,\;y = 5,\;z = 7),\;(x = 4,\;y = 6,\;z = 7)$$
$$\left(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2\right) \left(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3\right) \left(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4\right)=x^{18}+\color{red}{3 x^{17}}+6 x^{16}+10 x^{15}+12 x^{14}+12 x^{13}+10 x^{12}+6 x^{11}+3 x^{10}+x^9$$

Comment: You must have double counted some solutions. Besides, it is immediate from $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$ coefficient of $x^1$  is same as coefficient of $x^8$ since the polynomial coefficients are symmetric.

Comment: @Somos You are right I double counted some solutions and instead of removing those double countings I was trying to add those 3 solutions. So in actual I was triple counting them. When I removed the the extra countings i,e 3*2 then I got 42 which when subtracted from 45 gives the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then the constraints you had; then consider the following case where $x,y,z$ are the most they can be, i.e. $5$, $6$ and $7$:

$$5 + 6 + 7 = 18$$

$18$ is one more than $17$, which means that our solutions will be when only $x$ or only $y$ or only $z$ is one less than their maximum. We have $3$ terms, which means there must be $3$ solutions:

$$(5-1) + 6 + 7 = 17$$
$$5 + (6-1) + 7 = 17$$
$$5 + 6 + (7-1) = 17$$

Answer (score 0):

I double counted some solutions. The 3 solutions which I added to 45 to get 48 must be subtracted from 45 to get 42. This is because these 3 solutions were counted twice.